# Hibernate createSQLQuery multi entity explanation

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm reading the documentation and ran across this bit about native SQL with multi-entity queries.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#d5e3571  Specifically, this part:

> Alternatively, you can list the columns explicitly, but even in this case Hibernate injects the SQL column aliases for each property. The placeholder for a column alias is just the property name qualified by the table alias. In the following example, you retrieve Cats and their mothers from a different table (cat_log) to the one declared in the mapping metadata. You can even use the property aliases in the where clause.

```
String sql = "SELECT ID as {c.id}, NAME as {c.name}, " +
     "BIRTHDATE as {c.birthDate}, MOTHER_ID as {c.mother}, {mother.*} " +
     "FROM CAT_LOG c, CAT_LOG m WHERE {c.mother} = c.ID";

List loggedCats = sess.createSQLQuery(sql)
    .addEntity("cat", Cat.class)
    .addEntity("mother", Cat.class).list()
```

What I'm wondering about is the "cat" and "mother" in the addEntity() lines.  Neither cat not mother are specifically mentioned in the query, so I'm not sure what those are referring to.

I am trying to run a similar native SQL query returning properties from four different entities (joined in the SQL), but am choking on a "could not read column value from result set" error.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I am also having difficulties with SQL queries right now. Regadring your example I believe there is a typo in the documentation. Should'nt it be .addEntity("c", Cat.class) ?